# How can I fill a gridview using a connection to a ACCESS DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oledbconnection

How can I populate a `GridView` using a connection to an Access Database?

So far I have the following code:

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
OleDbCommand myCommand = default(OleDbCommand);
string strSQL = null;
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblLoginInfo " + "WHERE username='" + CustID.Replace("'", "''") + "' " + "AND password='" + CustPass.Replace("'", "''") + "';";
myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("login.mdb") + ";");

myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
```

But now what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 OleDbConnection myConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
         OleDbCommand myCommand = default(OleDbCommand);
         string strSQL = null;
         strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblLoginInfo " + "WHERE username='" + CustID.Replace("'", "''") + "' " + "AND password='" +
 CustPass.Replace("'", "''") + "';";
         myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + "Data Source="
 + Server.MapPath("login.mdb") + ";");
        myConnection.Open();
         myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);

         OleDbDataAdapter adp=new OledbDataAdapter(myCommand);
         dataset ds=new dataset();
         adp.fill(ds);
        gridview.datasource=ds;
        gridview.databind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/AccesFile.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TableName]">
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        </asp:GridView>
```

as mentioned in [AccessDataSource, SqlDataSource and connecting to Access databases in ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/78/AccessDataSource-SqlDataSource-and-connecting-to-Access-databases-in-ASP.NET)

Also I found this article about [Bind GridView with MS Access Database table in Asp.net](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/11/bind-gridview-with-ms-access-database.html)

Hope this helps